# How to get to class view in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I cant find the class view window/toolbar in Visual C# 2010 Express. Can someone tell me how to get it?

Comment: It is entirely possible that it simply doesn't exist, but have you changed into "advanced" mode? Most of the useful and interesting options are now hidden until you do this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's **View > Class View**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

It appears, by default, in the same tabbed window as the Solution Explorer.

At the same time, just like Marc said. You might be on the basic settings module, to change to expert settings go to **Tools > Settings > Expert** settings to enable this feature as well as few others.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to switch to "Expert Setting" ("Basic Settings" is turned on by default). Go to "Tools" -> "Settings" -> "Expert Settings". Now you should see a lot of new menu items including "View" -> "Class view".

Answer (score 3):

By default the 'View --> Class View" is hidden in 'Basic Setting'. However, switch to 'Expert Setting' reveal the option in 'View'

Switch to the expert setting (Tools --> Settings --> Expert Settings) THEN (View --> Class View)

Answer (score 0):

View->Class View

Normally, that's all I would have typed. However, StackOverflow complained that it was too short, so I added this paragraph.

Comment: Apart from there is no "View->Class View" by default